# Example of code that can execute to a binary file

Tags: c, linux

Does anyone have an example of code that can execute to a binary file.

Actually i have a binary file for LED BLINKING and i want to add this file in .c file.

Could you please tell me how can i resolve this problem.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by "code that can execute to a binary file"? Do you want to write a program that starts another program (the "binary file")?

Comment: yes unwind, i  want to write a program that starts another program (the "binary file")

Comment: Well, how about [the `system` function](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdlib.h/system) then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code which executes your binary like

```
int main()
{
   system("YOUR BINARY");
   return 0;
}
```